# How can I print a list of named lists from a JSON response in R?

Tags: r, httr

I'm writing a script in R that consumes a web API, which returns data in a big array of complex JSON objects, similar to:

```
[
    {
        "runIds": [9505160, 89098],
        "fileCount": 2,
        "runTime": 1.469,
        "requestCount": 1
    },
    {
        "runIds": [12, 13, 14],
        "fileCount": 1,
        "runTime": 2.9,
        "requestCount": 10
    }
]
```

I'm using the httr R package to do a GET request, which grabs this data and returns it as a list of lists. In case you're unfamiliar with the response format, check the output of this dummy R example:

```
library(httr)
response = GET("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
content(response)
```

Which prints something like:

```
[[10]]$company
[[10]]$company$name
[1] "Hoeger LLC"

[[10]]$company$catchPhrase
[1] "Centralized empowering task-force"

[[10]]$company$bs
[1] "target end-to-end models"
(...)
```

The printed response is hard to read. Is there any way to print this list of lists (of lists etc.) in a "prettified" way in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `jsonlite` package, you can transform it to a dataframe.

```
library(httr)

   response = GET("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")

   my_json_text <-content(response,as="text") 

library(jsonlite)

   my_df_output <- fromJSON(my_json_text)

   head(my_df_output,2)
```

which gives,

```
  id          name  username             email address.street address.suite address.city address.zipcode address.geo.lat address.geo.lng                 phone       website    company.name
1  1 Leanne Graham      Bret Sincere@april.biz    Kulas Light      Apt. 556  Gwenborough      92998-3874        -37.3159         81.1496 1-770-736-8031 x56442 hildegard.org Romaguera-Crona
2  2  Ervin Howell Antonette Shanna@melissa.tv  Victor Plains     Suite 879  Wisokyburgh      90566-7771        -43.9509        -34.4618   010-692-6593 x09125 anastasia.net    Deckow-Crist
                     company.catchPhrase                       company.bs
1 Multi-layered client-server neural-net      harness real-time e-markets
2         Proactive didactic contingency synergize scalable supply-chains
```

**EDIT:**

If the file includes list in lists, we can actually do the same thing as well like,

```
data <- '[
    {
        "runIds": [9505160, 89098],
        "fileCount": 2,
        "runTime": 1.469,
        "requestCount": 1
    },
    {
        "runIds": [12, 13, 14],
        "fileCount": 1,
        "runTime": 2.9,
        "requestCount": 10
    }
]'

 data2 <- fromJSON(data)
```

If we call `data2`,

```
data2
          runIds fileCount runTime requestCount
1 9505160, 89098         2   1.469            1
2     12, 13, 14         1   2.900           10


sapply(data2,class)

      runIds    fileCount      runTime requestCount 
      "list"    "integer"    "numeric"    "integer"
```

It is in list format. So we can store it as list format inside our dataframe which is more *prettified* comparing to the `content()` output or we can prefer to  transform it into a pure dataframe by ,

```
library(tidyverse)

data2 %>% unnest(runIds)
```

which gives,

```
  fileCount runTime requestCount  runIds
1         2   1.469            1 9505160
2         2   1.469            1   89098
3         1   2.900           10      12
4         1   2.900           10      13
5         1   2.900           10      14
```

Comment: This almost answers my question, except for the fact that this can only print a JSON structure that is not more than 1 level deep (an array of elements). However, the dataframe won't work in cases where a cell is a list itself, like in the JSON example provided.